# sapui5 Vizframe and IconTabBar

Tags: xml, sapui5

I want to develop a sapui5-view with a Tab-View. On the first tab there have to be two donut-charts (sap.viz.ui5.controls). For Tab-View I'm using the IconTabBar.

I can display the charts without the IconTabBar but when I implement the chart-view in the tab-view everthing is empty.

Also when I put the two donut-charts in a HorizontalLayout.

Has anyone an idea?
kind regards
Kirsten

Tab-View:

```
<Page id="detail_Tab" title="{i18n>Title}" showNavButton="false" >
        <IconTabBar>
            <items>
                <IconTabFilter text="Overview">
                    <mvc:XMLView viewName="{...}.view.Detail_Overview"/>
                </IconTabFilter>

            </items>
        </IconTabBar>
    </Page>
```

Detail_Overview:

```
    <viz:VizFrame 
        id="idDonutChartPriority" 
        height="100%" 
        width="100%"></viz:VizFrame>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you have a problem with the `height="100%"` property of your `VizFrame`s. Try setting them to a px size. You can try that [here](https://jsbin.com/kuwuceduku/2/edit?html,js,output) on JSBin.

The height of the `IconTabBar` is fitted to its contents. If your Content has a height of 100% it will result into 100% of zero.

If you want to use 100% you could try to set `stretchContentHeight="true"` on your `IconTabBar`. It [determines whether the IconTabBar height is stretched to the maximum possible height of its parent container. As a prerequisite, the height of the parent container must be defined as a fixed value.](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IconTabBar.html#getStretchContentHeight)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" controllerName="view1">
<IconTabBar>
          <items>
              <IconTabFilter text="Overview">
                  <viz:VizFrame 
                    id="sample" 
                    height="500px" 
                    width="100%"></viz:VizFrame>
              </IconTabFilter>
          </items>
      </IconTabBar>
</mvc:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess, that you made the same mistake I did and copied the sample code blindly, without realizing that some of the properties are meant to be used with `layout` elements.

Unless you are using another container for the `VizFrame` simply remove the `height="100%"` property from VizFrame and it will adapt on its own.