# Line chart doesn't show in Object Page - Vizframe - SAPUI5

Tags: charts, line, sapui5

I am trying to make a **line chart** using Vizframe in an **Object Page**. Does anybody have an example how to do it? I searched the APIs and the sdn but find just samples with Layout element and not Object Page Layout element.
 So when I test it within a simple Layout element (< layout > element) the line charts works fine. But when I try it with Object Page Layout elementt, the chart doesn't show and there is no errors in the console.

Thanks a lot,

Haylee N.

I joined the two different views here:

**View.xml with Layout element ( that works )**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:u="sap.uxap" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f"
    xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data"
    xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" xmlns:sample="test.controller.ChartsOverview"
    xmlns:goals="test.view.goals" controllerName="test.controller.ChartsOverview"
    height="100%">

    <Page title="SAPUI5 App">
        <layout:FixFlex id='chartFixFlex' minFlexSize="250">
            <layout:fixContent>
                <Panel id='settingsPanel' class="panelStyle" expandable="true"
                    expanded="true" headerText="Summary" width="auto">
                    <content>
                        <HBox class='settingsHBox'>
                            <VBox width="200px">
                                <Label text='Reports' design="Bold" class='settingsLabel'></Label>
                            </VBox>
                        </HBox>
                    </content>
                </Panel>
            </layout:fixContent>
            <layout:flexContent>
                <viz:Popover id="idPopOver"></viz:Popover>
                <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
                    height='50%' width="50%" vizType='timeseries_line'>
                    <viz:dataset>
                        <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/milk}">
                            <viz.data:dimensions>
                                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Date"
                                    value="{Date}" dataType="date" />
                            </viz.data:dimensions>
                            <viz.data:measures>
                                <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Revenue"
                                    value="{Revenue}" />
                            </viz.data:measures>
                        </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                    </viz:dataset>

                    <viz:feeds>
                        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure"
                            values="Revenue" />
                        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="timeAxis" type="Dimension"
                            values="Date" />
                    </viz:feeds>
                </viz:VizFrame>
            </layout:flexContent>
        </layout:FixFlex>
    </Page>

</mvc:View>
```

**View.xml with Object Page Layout element ( that doesn't work )**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns="sap.uxap" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f"
    xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data"
    xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" xmlns:sample="test.controller.ChartsOverview"
    xmlns:goals="test.view.goals" controllerName="test.controller.ChartsOverview"
    height="100%">
    <m:Page showHeader="true" title="{i18n>appTitle}" showFooter="true"
        showNavButton="false">
        <ObjectPageLayout id="ObjectPageLayout"
            enableLazyLoading="false" subSectionLayout="TitleOnLeft"
            showTitleInHeaderContent="true" showHeaderContent="true">
            <headerTitle>
                <ObjectPageHeader objectTitle="Quality Monitor"
                    objectSubtitle="Reports based on errors processed"
                    isObjectIconAlwaysVisible="false" isObjectTitleAlwaysVisible="false"
                    isObjectSubtitleAlwaysVisible="false" isActionAreaAlwaysVisible="true"
                    id="ObjectPageLayoutHeaderTitle">
                    <actions>
                    </actions>
                </ObjectPageHeader>
            </headerTitle>

            <sections>

                <ObjectPageSection title="Charts">
                    <subSections>
                        <ObjectPageSubSection>
                            <blocks>
                                <viz:Popover id="idPopOver"></viz:Popover>
                                <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
                                    height='50%' width="50%" vizType='timeseries_line'>
                                    <viz:dataset>
                                        <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/milk}">
                                            <viz.data:dimensions>
                                                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition
                                                    name="Date" value="{Date}" dataType="date" />
                                            </viz.data:dimensions>
                                            <viz.data:measures>
                                                <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Revenue"
                                                    value="{Revenue}" />
                                            </viz.data:measures>
                                        </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                                    </viz:dataset>

                                    <viz:feeds>
                                        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure"
                                            values="Revenue" />
                                        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="timeAxis" type="Dimension"
                                            values="Date" />
                                    </viz:feeds>
                                </viz:VizFrame>
                            </blocks>

                        </ObjectPageSubSection>
                    </subSections>
                </ObjectPageSection>

            </sections>
        </ObjectPageLayout>
    </m:Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Have you seen the following sample? [Sample Line](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Line/preview) and [Code: Line](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Line/code)

Comment: Yeah I tried it, it works. But when I try it in my project, it doesn't work. Above there is my code. Anyway, thank you for your proposal :).

Comment: You say “it doesn’t work”.
Do you get any error messages in the console or just an empty screen?
Can you see in the debugger if the data is loaded ?
Is it possible for you to create a sample with your coding in a tool like https://plnkr.co/ ?
This might help debugging the issue.

Comment: The issue is from ObjectPageLayout element, because when I use a simple Layout element the line chart works perfectly. No I didn't get any error message in the console. The chart just doesn't show up. Yes, the data is loaded correctly. Yes I tried plnkr but there is some files that failed to be saved.. so..

Comment: I finally found the solution for this. :)

Comment: @HayleeN. why did you keep it for yourself then?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by people in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652194/sapui5-vizframe-and-icontabbar/59624780#59624780) some controls use adaptive containers that adapt height to fit their content. If that content uses "100%" of height (which is initially 0) the content efectively becomes `0px` and those controls end up adapting their hight to 0px height of the content. For the same reason if you use fixed height instead of a percentage it actually works.

For me personally, **this problem only occurred because I blindly copied sample code** for `VizFrame` into `IconTabBar` container, without realizing the difference in containers used.

**Solution to my problem:** remove the `height="100%"` property from VizFrame, which will not force height and in turn will allow the height of VizFrame to be calculated based on its content (title, actual chart, legend and such), instead of container that VizFrame is placed into.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever may come here for an answer, giving the height of vizframe with pixels does the trick.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer finally explains why all of the official samples are placed in various layout blocks.