# Vizframe line chart does not show in object page section

Tags: sapui5

I have a line chart in my sapui5 app and I want to put it in an object page subsection. When I put it in a normal layout in a page, it's working. But when I separate it in a fragment and call from object page subsection nothing is shown.

here is my fragment :

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data" height="100%" xmlns:common="sap.suite.ui.commons">
    <layout:FixFlex>
        <layout:flexContent>
            <viz:Popover id="idPopOver"></viz:Popover>
            <viz:VizFrame id="idLineGraph" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" height='100%' width="100%" vizType='line'></viz:VizFrame>
        </layout:flexContent>
    </layout:FixFlex>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

and here is my subsection:

```
<ux:ObjectPageSection id="idChart" title="{i18n>chartSection}" titleUppercase="false">
                            <ux:subSections>
                                <ux:ObjectPageSubSection>
                                    <ux:blocks>
                                        <core:Fragment id="idChartFragment" fragmentName="mynamespace.zmm_stok_list.fragments.grafik" type="XML"/>
                                    </ux:blocks>
                                </ux:ObjectPageSubSection>
                            </ux:subSections>
                        </ux:ObjectPageSection>
```

I also saw that question [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554229/line-chart-doesnt-show-in-object-page-vizframe-sapui5) but it looks like OP have preferred to keep that answer which hi's found for himself.

lastly, there a blog about almost same thing but using cds views.[blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/27/smart-charts-in-object-pages-using-abap-cds-annotations/)

But you know cds views are not like xml views and I guess they are generated automatically and we can not see which componenets are used.

Answer (score 0):

So I still couldn't found a way to do this that way. But if I put my vizframe in object layout section directly (not seperated in a fragment) and give the height of vizframe with pixels it works. Not much but I'm ok with this.

Ps: When vizframe is seperated in a fragment, giving its height with pixels does not work either.